# Python - How tu jump lines in files while in writing mode?

Tags: python

I got this code running but when I enter my inputs and go to see the file, all words are next to each other (no spaces no line jumps). Any clue how to fix that?
I tried `fid.write(w "\n")` and `fid.write(w,"\n")` didn't work.

```
fid=open("w&c","w")
for x in range (0, 2):
    w=input("Enter a word: ")
    fid.write(w)
    c1=input("Enter a clue: ")
    fid.write(c1)
    c2=input("Enter a clue: ")
    fid.write(c2)
    c3=input("Enter a clue: ")
    fid.write(c3)
fid.close()
```

[This is what happens.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8phdx.png)

Comment: write '\n' caracter to file

Comment: as a next step consider separating into at least two fucntions - one for obtaining inputs, other for storing  to file, as a little excercise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the `+` sine to add `\n` to it, try the code below:

```
fid=open("w&c","w")
for x in range (0, 2):
    w=input("Enter a word: ")
    fid.write(w+'\n')
    c1=input("Enter a clue: ")
    fid.write(c1+'\n')
    c2=input("Enter a clue: ")
    fid.write(c2+'\n')
    c3=input("Enter a clue: ")
    fid.write(c3+'\n')
fid.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can append newline characters with

```
fid.write(w +  "\n")
```